# what is eval/seq/number.js in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

I really  dont understand the need of the eval/seq/number.js and its effect on the web page.

When i am dynamically loading the js files i found the pages to be in /eval/seq/some.js directory .Only  issue iam facing is unable debug the code as the debug point never stop the flow.Any alternate to debug the code and any issues if the js file loads dynamically that is in eval/seq/.......js.

found the numbers increase when i reload the page 
ex:

```
eval/seq/1.js
eval/seq/2.js

after reloading page
eval/seq/3.js
eval/seq/4.js
```

Please help me out and how to debug it.

Comment: You can add [`debugger` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) to have execution pause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the script contains uses of `eval` or it adds `<script>` tags dynamically. Developer tools displays the code that is executed this way as if they were in files with these names.